# How can I make a table like that in Latex?

Tags: latex

I can't do it, it is really hard and I don't know how to change color of letters.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need only two special commands for this table:

- colours can be changed with `\textcolor{colorname}{text}` from the `xcolor` package
- for cells spanning multiple columns, you can use `\multicolumn{number of column}{alignment}{text}`

I won't code the whole table for you, but this should give you a starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{text}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{text}\\
\midrule
& text1 & text2 & text3 & text4\\
\midrule
\textcolor{red}{text} & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but ı get an error about usepackage ,'File `booktabs.sty' not found. \usepackage' How can ı fix that error ?

Comment: @AliSAĞLAM You have to install this package with your tex distribution. Are you using miktex, mactex or texlive?

Comment: I'm using miktex

Comment: I can't do it :(( , could you please write the table, please

Comment: ♀@samcarter can you help me ?

Comment: @AliSAĞLAM Can you show what you tried to do and describe which problems you faced? Just saying "I can't do it" is way too broad to give you any response that will help you understand.

Comment: My teacher gave an assigment about Latex, but ı don't know how can ı use latex actually . I don't know how can ı download usepackage and how can ı make table or equation , ı was able to write equation but ı didn't write label of equaiton . I tried lots of thing on example which one is your sent, bu ı can't solve

Comment: @AliSAĞLAM In this case I highly recommend https://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/  A very good book for learning latex and a free version is available on the website to download.

Comment: How can ı write (2.1) like in en of the equation ?